# Obtain BigQuery table list in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I would like to use the Google bigquery gem (https://rubygems.org/gems/bigquery) to create an Array of table names. So far, this is what I have written:

```
require 'json'

bqRepsonse = bq.tables('myDataSet')

bqRepsonseCleaned = bqRepsonse.to_s.gsub("=>", ":")

data = JSON.parse(bqRepsonseCleaned)

tableListing = []

data["tableID"]["type"].each do |item| 
  case item["type"]
  when 'TABLE'
  bqTableList << item["tableId"]
  else
  end
end
```

If I print bqResponse, I get this result:

> [{"kind"=>"bigquery#table",
>   "id"=>"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableA",
>   "tableReference"=>{"projectId"=>"curious-idea-532",
>   "datasetId"=>"dataset_test_4", "tableId"=>"TableA"}, "type"=>"TABLE"},
>   {"kind"=>"bigquery#table",
>   "id"=>"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableB",
>   "tableReference"=>{"projectId"=>"curious-idea-532",
>   "datasetId"=>"dataset_test_4", "tableId"=>"TableB"}, "type"=>"TABLE"},
>   {"kind"=>"bigquery#table",
>   "id"=>"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableC",
>   "tableReference"=>{"projectId"=>"curious-idea-532",
>   "datasetId"=>"dataset_test_4", "tableId"=>"TableC"}, "type"=>"TABLE"},
>   {"kind"=>"bigquery#table",
>   "id"=>"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableD",
>   "tableReference"=>{"projectId"=>"curious-idea-532",
>   "datasetId"=>"dataset_test_4", "tableId"=>"TableD"}, "type"=>"TABLE"}]

And running the code throws and error

> `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Not sure where to correct this. My desired outcome is:

> tableListing = ["TableA","TableB","TableC","TableD"]

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```rb
require 'json'

string = '[{"kind": "bigquery#table", "id": "curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableA", "tableReference" : {"projectId":"curious-idea-532", "datasetId":"dataset_test_4", "tableId":"TableA"}, "type":"TABLE"}, {"kind":"bigquery#table", "id":"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableB", "tableReference":{"projectId":"curious-idea-532", "datasetId":"dataset_test_4", "tableId":"TableB"}, "type":"TABLE"}, {"kind":"bigquery#table", "id":"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableC", "tableReference":{"projectId":"curious-idea-532", "datasetId":"dataset_test_4", "tableId":"TableC"}, "type":"TABLE"}, {"kind":"bigquery#table", "id":"curious-idea-532:dataset_test_4.TableD", "tableReference":{"projectId":"curious-idea-532", "datasetId":"dataset_test_4", "tableId":"TableD"}, "type":"TABLE"}]'

data = JSON.parse(string)

tableListing = []

# Here we are iterating over the data instead of its child element
data.each do |item| 
  case item["type"]
  when 'TABLE'
    tableListing << item["tableReference"]["tableId"]
  else
  end
end

puts tableListing
```